# Как взаимоувязать формулы LaTeX с MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, latex

Вопрос возможно несколько не по теме сайта, но всё же Matlab является языком программирования.
Я использую команду `\input` дабы вставлять формулы, а также их расшифровку в свои отчёты, однако они не являются интерактивными. А возможно ли взаимодействие формул LaTeX с расчётами в Matlab или это только мои фантазии? Может быть их можно взаимоувязать с другой расчётной средой, но главное чтобы результаты расчётов синхронизировались с изменениями в расчётной программе.

**Я себе это представлю так:**
У вас есть скрипт в MatLab и на определенных пикетах во время его выполнение matlab(или другая программа) должна будет сохранять формулы в LaTeX формат (без всяких приамбул, только `\begin{equation}` и `end{equation}`. А отдельно сформированных отчёт в `.tex` просто автоматически формировал новый отчёт благодаря функции `input`